# importar base de dados MySQL de 1,2GB

Tags: mysql

Estou tendo dificuldade em importar, ele para o processo no meio do caminho.

Quanto tempo demora em média para importar uma base MySQL de 1,2GB em um Core 2 Duo com linux?

Comment: Podes juntar à pergunta a maneira como estás a importar?

Comment: Porquê os votos para fechar?

Comment: Qual comando você está usando para importar?

Comment: A sua base de dados contém tabelas grandes, ou ela é composta de um monte de tabelas pequenas?

Comment: eu uso o comando do mysqldump pelo terminal do linux, ela contém tabelas médias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu já consegui resolver o problema. Na verdade tinha dado um pau na hora de processar pelo terminal e ficou numa execução infinita...

Eu exportei pelo MySQL Workbench e deu tudo certo.

Answer (score 0):

Para importart tabelas grandes a melhor maneira é através da linha de comando com arquivos .sql. Caso esteja tentando carregar em um phpmyadmin da vida vai ser complicado, não recomendo.

Para fazer isso, conecte-se ao mysql através do seguinte comando:

```
mysql -u usuario_do_bd -p base_de_dados_a_ser_utilizada(opicional) < path/to/file.sql
```